# JSON data format write to InfluxDB error results in 204 response

Tags: python, influxdb

I am requesting some data from the weather API and I am trying to save it to a influxdb database.

When I am trying to write the json data to the influx database I get a 204 response and no data are written to the database. The exact error from the docker logs is:

`[httpd] 172.17.0.1 - root [17/Jun/2020:23:00:35 +0000] "POST /write?db=external_weather HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "python-requests/2.23.0" 5ac727b3-b0ee-11ea-8152-0242ac110002 169`

My code is:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
payload = {
    "lat": 51.509865,
    "lon": -0.118092,
    # "exclude": {"minute", "hourly", "daily"},
    "appid": "xxx",
    "units": "metric"}


try:  

    responce = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    responce.raise_for_status()
    json_responce = [responce.json()]
    print(responce.status_code)


except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')

except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')


# Send to InfluxDB


'''
'''
client = InfluxDBClient()
client.write_points(json_responce, database='external_weather')
print(json_responce)
```

the json_responce holds the following information:

```
[{'coord': {'lon': -0.12, 'lat': 51.51}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10n'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 16.14, 'feels_like': 15.39, 'temp_min': 15.56, 'temp_max': 16.67, 'pressure': 1012, 'humidity': 71}, 'wind': {'speed': 1.49, 'deg': 143}, 'rain': {'1h': 0.9}, 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'dt': 1592435463, 'sys': {'type': 3, 'id': 268730, 'country': 'GB', 'sunrise': 1592451762, 'sunset': 1592511641}, 'timezone': 3600, 'id': 2643743, 'name': 'London', 'cod': 200}]
```

I don't understand why influx refuses to accept the data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the `InfluxDBClient`, the `204` response code is actually expected when writing data into the influx DB, see https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write

Please double check if there really is an issue with writing data into influx in your case.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that 204 means success but It does not write any data to the database. I query the database with both CLI - SHOW MEASUREMENTS and Grafana and both return nothing. I am pretty sure the database has no measurements.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may originate from the time formatting of Influx DB.
Openweathermap is using UNIX timestamps in seconds, while Influx requires them in nanoseconds.